# user interface in visual c++ using opencv

Tags: opencv

I'm new to OpenCV. I have completed my project but I'm having difficulty with the GUI.

Can you provide me some links that can help me out? I'm using C++ and OpenCV 2.1 and Visual Studio 2005.

regards
sidra shahbaz

Answer (score 0):

`highgui.h` handles the GUI functionality and more. The [High-level GUI Wiki entry](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/user_interface.html) describes all the function in detail.